# how to prevent execution of same thing again and again

Tags: java, android

I have made an application that whenever a user types a particular word it toast a massage now I want to add a feature that if the user has typed the particular word continuously many times in a particular time it will consider it once only and toast the massage ones only.

The code

```java
if ( string.equals("help") ) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "we are here to help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a global String variable let's name it as `lastText` and check whether input text is the same as last text.

#### UPDATE for time tracking

```java
private String lastText = ""; // Global for all class members
private long lastTextTime = 0; // Global
//...
// May be more code goes here
//...
if ( string.equals("help") && !string.equals(lastText) ) {
    // Check whether 5 min has elapsed to show the toast message
    if(System.currentTimeMillis - lastTextTime > (5*60*1000)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "we are here to help", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // If the program reach here save this string as a last text for the next check
        lastText = string;
        lastTextTime = System.currentTimeMillis;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can do that for a particular time, so that it will only toast ones in 5 min even if the user types it multiple times within that 5 min it will toast it ones

Comment: Are the text inputs constant? How many inputs are there? If you don't mind to show more of your code please go ahead and post it. This will help us to provide better solutions. Because the information you've given is very limited and left us with many questions.

Comment: yes the text input is constant

Comment: well, I'll show you an example of how to track the time for one input since you provide no more information.

Answer (score -1):

You can add already typed words to a list, and when the user types a word, you can iterate through this list and check if "word" is already was typed, and then if "false" - show toast.

Alternative solution - you can create a local SQLite database (using Room persistence library), it will allow you to save values even if user restart/exit app, but it will require more coding and fixing nuances